# How to convert comma separated string of local storage into numeric array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a one-dimensional array of integer in JavaScript that I'd like to add data from comma separated string, Is there a simple way to do this?

e.g : var strVale = "130,235,342,124 ";

Comment: `strVale.split(',')` will give you an array of values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split and then use `parseInt` to convert it into integer array.

```js
//get this from localStorage
var strValue = "130,235,342,124"; 
var res = strValue.split(',').map(x=>{return parseInt(x)});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `split` function like:

```js
 var strVal = "130,235,342,124";
 console.log(strVal.split(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a simple way to do that? Yes!
Just use 2 simple functions: `concat` and `split`:

```
var str = "130,235,342,124";
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.concat(str.split(','));

//result:
//arr = ["1", "2", "3", "130", "235", "342", "124"];
```

**EDIT:**
for integer arrays (just add `map` function):

```
var str = "130,235,342,124";
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.concat(str.split(',').map(Number));

//result:
//arr = [1, 2, 3, 130, 235, 342, 124];
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact you can use `myValues.split(",")` to get the array - one common use of localStorage is to store your array as String like:

```
var myArray = [130,235,342,124];

// Send Array to localStorage:
localStorage.myStuff = JSON.stringify( myArray );

// Get Array from localStorage
myArray = JSON.parse( localStorage.myStuff );
```

Another common fallback to empty array on application init is:

```
// get array from localStorage or set to empty array:
var myArray = JSON.parse( localStorage.myStuff || "[]" );
```